# Evaluate the Integral $\int\frac{(1+e^x)^2}{e^x}dx$

Tags: calculus

$\int\frac{(1+e^x)^2}{e^x}\ dx$

$u=e^x$

$du=e^x\ dx$

$\frac{du}{e^x}=dx$

$e^{-x}\ du$

$\int\frac{(1+u)^2}{u}\frac{du}{e^x}$

I am on the right track?

Comment: No, you can't, you don't simplify $e^x$ with $e^{-x}$.

Comment: Can you explain why this is the case?

Comment: $1/e^x = e^{-x}$.  So $(1/e^x) * e^{-x} = e^{-x} * e^{-x} = e^{-2x}$.

Comment: @ Michael Seifert can you take a look at the problem and solve it in the way I am attempting to do so (top to bottom)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align*} \frac{(1+e^x)^2}{e^x} &= \frac{(1+e^x)(1+e^x)}{e^x} \\ &= \frac{1+e^x+e^x+(e^x)^2}{e^x} \\ &= \frac{1+2e^x+(e^x)^2}{e^x} \\ &= \frac{1}{e^x} + \frac{2e^x}{e^x} + \frac{(e^x)^2}{e^x} \\ &= e^{-x} + 2 + e^x. \end{align*}$$  Now integrate each term (leaving the constant of integration for the last step when you put everything back together):

$$\int e^{-x} \, dx = -e^{-x},$$ which you can check by differentiating.

$$\int 2 \, dx = 2x$$ since the derivative of $2x$ is $2$.

$$\int e^x \, dx = e^x.$$  So the result is $$\int \frac{(1+e^x)^2}{e^x} \, dx = -e^{-x} + 2x + e^x + C.$$

Comment: Great job! Nonetheless, can you give me the power and integration rule for  $\int e^{-x} \, dx = -e^{-x}$ ? I ma aware of$\frac{d}{dx}x^n=nx^{n-1}$ and $\int x^ndx=\frac{x^n+1}{n+1}+C$ but I can not figure out how you calculated your answer

Comment: @Cetshwayo We know that $$\frac{d}{dx} [ e^x ] = e^x.$$  So using the Chain rule, we know that $$\frac{d}{dx} \left[ e^{f(x)} \right] = e^{f(x)} \frac{df}{dx}.$$  Therefore, the derivative of $e^{-x}$ is $-e^{-x}$ (with the choice $f(x) = -x$), and consequently, an antiderivative of $-e^{-x}$ is $e^{-x}$.  It follows that an antiderivative of $e^{-x}$ is $-e^{-x}$.

Answer (score 0):

If you differentiate your answer, you will see that it isn't correct.

Instead, notice that: $$(1+e^x)^2e^{-x}=(1+2e^x+e^{2x})e^{-x}=e^{-x}+2+e^{x},$$ so the primitive is: $$-e^{-x}+2x+e^{x}+c.$$

Comment: You should be more careful before claiming mistakes: $e^{2x}\,e^{-x}=e^x$.

Comment: I do't follow what you did. Can you follow my layout (top to bottom) and express your steps?

Comment: @JuliánAguirre I never claimed I didn't make one :P

Comment: @Sonner Your answer is wrong. The second term of the last line must be $2x$.

Comment: Ok fine I should have just said "and the result easily follows"...

Answer (score 0):

Take $e^{x}=u$, $du=e^{x}dx$ to get $$\int\frac{\left(1+e^{x}\right)^{2}}{e^{x}}dx=\int\frac{\left(1+u\right)^{2}}{u^{2}}du=\int\frac{u^{2}+2u+1}{u^{2}}du
 $$ so we have $$=\int\frac{u^{2}+2u+1}{u^{2}}du=\int\frac{u^{2}}{u^{2}}du+\int\frac{2u}{u^{2}}du+\int\frac{1}{u^{2}}du=$$ $$=u+2\log(u)-\frac{1}{u}+C$$ now substitute back.

Comment: You skipped to many steps. I can't follow what you did. If I knew how to solve the problem I wouldn't be asking.

Comment: Ok I will add some steps.

Comment: Where did the $u^2$ come from. I understand you replaced the $e^x$ terms with $u$ but I am confused as to why u is squared. And what happened to $\frac{du}{e^x}$ = dx?

Comment: @Cetshwayo Note that $u=e^{x}$ so from that you have $dx=du/u$.

Comment: @avid19 You're right ;)

Comment: @MarcoCantarini Actually since $u=e^x$ and $e^x>0$, it's okay to not have $|u|$ there but it is just something that might have been addressed. Either way +1

Comment: Look at my edit and tell me where I am going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @Cetshwayo Using the substitution you have $e^{x}=u$ so from your actual form you get the $u^{2}$ at the denominator, like me. If you want, use the equivalent substitution $x=\log(u)$.